# Scraping sound when I get off car

Tags: suspension, noise

Whenever I get off my car (2008 Corolla S), I hear a scraping sound (only when its in parking brake). This is more noticeable for people getting from the back. Its a very metallic grrrr. I can hear it in our other (2010 Corolla LE) car but its more subtle.

I don't know if this is because of the difference of weight on the suspension/ joints, but if it is causing harm, I'd prefer it to be fixed.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have heard a similar sound in my 2011 Toyota Yaris I used to have, where the sound could be heard even when I was in the driver's seat pressing brakes lightly, and somebody enters or exits the car. I think it just means the brake does not have enough force to keep the car completely stationary. The car had rear drum main brakes and discs on front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get out of the car, the weight reduction causes the car to rise on its suspension slightly, which (depending on suspension design) can rotate the wheels slightly. If you've engaged the brakes with insufficient force to lock the wheels, the brake pads will drag across the disk/drum, making the grinding sound you hear.

Testing without the brake engaged will confirm this.

The solution is to either pull up the handbrake more when you apply it, or to have the handbrake adjusted, although many handbrakes are self-adjusting these days. Worst case, the brake pads are worn out.

Answer (score 1):

The noise is likely coming from the rear brakes.. Try stopping on a level surface somewhere, then get out of the car with the hand brake off. If the noise has gone away then your rear brakes likely need attention.